# JSS deployment issue with react, using JSS Tech Preview 4

Tags: jss

JSS deployment issue with react, using Tech Preview 4.

Here is the complete log:

```
PS F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app> jss deploy app -c -d
JSS is creating a manifest for my-first-jss-app to ./sitecore/manifest...
Cleaning path ./sitecore/manifest...
Cleaned:
 F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data\media
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data\media\files
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data\media\files\jss.pdf
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data\media\img
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data\media\img\jss_logo.png
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\data\media\img\sc_logo.png
F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app\sitecore\manifest\sitecore-import.json
Enabling Babel transpilation for the manifest...
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.js' did not match any files.
path or pattern './sitecore/pipelines/**/*.patch.ts' did not match any files.
copied media from: ./data/media/img/sc_logo.png to: sitecore\manifest\data\media\img\sc_logo.png
copied media from: ./data/media/img/jss_logo.png to: sitecore\manifest\data\media\img\jss_logo.png
copied media from: ./data/media/files/jss.pdf to: sitecore\manifest\data\media\files\jss.pdf
Manifest has been generated and written to ./sitecore/manifest/sitecore-import.json
JSS is manifest packaging my-first-jss-app to ./sitecore/package...
Adding data/media/files/jss.pdf
Adding data/media/img/jss_logo.png
Adding data/media/img/sc_logo.png
Adding sitecore-import.json
Wrote sitecore\package\my-first-jss-app.1534334605998.manifest.zip
Sending package sitecore\package\my-first-jss-app.1534334605998.manifest.zip to http://jssreactweb/sitecore/api/jss/import...
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Internal Server Error
Body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Could not find base site 'website' for site 'my-first-jss-app'.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Could not find base site 'website' for site 'my-first-jss-app'.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find base site 'website' for site 'my-first-jss-app'.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: Could not find base site &#39;website&#39; for site &#39;my-first-jss-app&#39;.]
   Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.AddInheritedProperties(Site site, SafeDictionary`2 siteDictionary) +447
   Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.ResolveInheritance(SiteCollection sites, SafeDictionary`2 siteDictionary) +174
   Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.InitializeSites() +716
   Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.GetSites() +18
   System.Linq.&lt;SelectManyIterator&gt;d__17`2.MoveNext() +292
   Sitecore.Sites.SiteCollection.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 sites) +84
   Sitecore.Sites.SitecoreSiteProvider.GetSites() +218
   Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSites() +255
   Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String hostName, String fullPath, Int32 portNumber) +124
   Sitecore.Pipelines.PreAuthenticateRequest.SiteResolver.ResolveSiteContext(HttpRequestArgs args) +579
   Sitecore.Pipelines.PreAuthenticateRequest.SiteResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args) +14
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnBeginRequest(HttpContextBase context) +207
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs ) +77
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +88
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2556.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!--
[InvalidOperationException]: Could not find base site &#39;website&#39; for site &#39;my-first-jss-app&#39;.
   at Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.AddInheritedProperties(Site site, SafeDictionary`2 siteDictionary)
   at Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.ResolveInheritance(SiteCollection sites, SafeDictionary`2 siteDictionary)
   at Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.InitializeSites()
   at Sitecore.Sites.ConfigSiteProvider.GetSites()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Sites.SiteCollection.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 sites)
   at Sitecore.Sites.SitecoreSiteProvider.GetSites()
   at Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSites()
   at Sitecore.Sites.DefaultSiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String hostName, String fullPath, Int32 portNumber)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.PreAuthenticateRequest.SiteResolver.ResolveSiteContext(HttpRequestArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.PreAuthenticateRequest.SiteResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnBeginRequest(HttpContextBase context)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
PS F:\Drive\my-first-jss-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSS Tech Preview 4 works fine on a fresh installed Sitecore 9, but it was breaking on my another machine.

Whereas if you were using the older Sitecore Instance with Tech Preview 3 and installing new react app with Tech Preview 4 on it, You will get the above issue.

JSS Tech preview 3 was using JSS Server 8.x whereas JSS Tech Preview 4 is using 9.x.

You need to update:

- JSS Version
- Upgrade JSS Cli
- Add deployment secret (which is new in Tech 4)
- Upgrade Placeholers

**Complete guide how to upgrade your JSS Server.**

http://jss.sitecore.net/upgrade-guides/manifest-packages